# I don't have any products BUT I have products in categories!

Tags: magento-1.9, category

No products in my magento. None. No data to export from products.

YET, I have product counts next to categories in the cat management area.

WHAT GIVES?

thanks

Comment: Try php bin/magento indexer:reindex then check product counts again

Comment: Which magento version are you using ?

Comment: 1.9, sorry i didnt include that

Comment: i have reindexed more times then trump has lied

Comment: check if your products are associated to right website and store and also have quantity and enabled

Comment: Can you share the URL please?

Comment: "check if your products"... omm, what products? i dont have any!

Comment: running php bin/magento indexer:reindex did not work